# Having trouble getting an output

Tags: javascript, towers-of-hanoi

Ok so i have this Towers of Hanoi program... You enter the number of discs and it outputs the number of moves it would take to complete it. for some reason im not getting an output. I know its probably something small but any help would be appreciated.

```js
var count = 0;
var numberOfPlates = document.getElementById("numPlates").value;
moveDisk(numberOfPlates, "A", "C", "B");

function moveDisk(N, A, C, B) {

  if (N == 1)
    count = count + 1;

  if (N > 1) {
    moveDisk(N - 1, A, B, C);
    count = count + 1;
    moveDisk(N - 1, B, C, A);
  }
}
  document.getElementById("moveOutput").innerHTML = "Move Count = " + count;
```

```html
<h1>Towers of Hanoi</h1> Enter the number of discs:
<input type="textbox" id="numPlates" />
<input type="button" id="Move" value="Move Disks" onClick="moveDisk();" />
<p id="moveOutput"></p>
```

Comment: You call your function but pass no parameters `onClick="moveDisk();`

Comment: your output line appears to be outside the function...

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, you call your function with no parameters on key click.
The quickest way to fix this is to put your entire code in another function (say `startCaluclation()`) that takes no parameters, but just collects the input and runs `moveDisk`, then put that function's name in the `onClick` event.

Answer (score 0):

Should look like this then...

```js
function moveDisks() {
  var count = 0;
  var numberOfPlates = document.getElementById("numPlates").value;
  calculation(numberOfPlates, "A", "C", "B");

  function calculation(N, A, C, B) {

    if (N == 1)
      count = count + 1;

    if (N > 1) {
      calculation(N - 1, A, B, C);
      count = count + 1;
      calculation(N - 1, B, C, A);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("moveOutput").innerHTML = "Move Count = " + count;
}
```

```html
<h1>Towers of Hanoi</h1> Enter the number of discs:
<input type="textbox" id="numPlates" />
<input type="button" id="Move" value="Move Disks" onClick="moveDisks();" />
<p id="moveOutput"></p>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.